# UI Automation via Instruments hanging on Logging element tree

Tags: ios, instruments, ui-automation

Firstly I want to apologise for this general question but I'm currently trying to investigate why my UI Automation script fails at a certain point:

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()["ExampleId"].tap();
```

the error indicates that the element is not available:

invalid element: UIAElementNil etc...

When attempting to log the element tree before this point, it starts but never finishes.

My question is what are the reasons why logging an element tree would hang like this?

```
I'm using this to log the element tree:
UIALogger.logStart("Logging element tree ...");
UIATarget.localTarget().logElementTree();
UIALogger.logPass();
```

So just to be clear, this is not a question about why a specific ElementId is not present, but why automation is put in this infinite state of trying to log the element tree.

Comment: Not sure, UIAutomation in the mobile space is relatively immature, sometimes stuff just doesn't really work and it's hard to tell why. Does `UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().logElementTree();` work ok?

Comment: Props to you ekcrisp, .frontMostApp() was used prior but not at that point. After executing that we were able to see the element log.